# iPhone Web services and table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a table view that is getting it's data from a web service via an xml parser. I can get the data just fine on the first view now my problem is that when i select a row it should take me to a second with that has a table as well and i should select a row there to go to a third details view, i can't seem to be able to get the second view to load the data based on the first view selection! Now should i get a different url for each view with some data and if so how can i load the data based on the previous view's selection?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
MySub1ViewController *mySub1ViewController = [[MySub1ViewController alloc] init];

//Push it to the top of the navigation controllers stack
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:mySub1ViewController animated:YES];

//Pop viewController from the view stack
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)YES];
```

where `MySub1ViewController` viewcontroller should instantiate your second tableView. Now you need to pass data from the `currentViewController` to this `MySub1ViewController`

For more check this [tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/)

Comment: The problem is not about the navigation but how to handle the data from one view to the other based on the user selection and the data that are parsed from the web service, should we parse it on each view and if so how can we tie it to the selection from the previous view?